# Django3 ListView with Conditional WHERE

Tags: django

I have simple ListView in Django 3:

```
path("show/<int:pk>", ApplicantListView.as_view(), name='applicant-list'),
```

my view is as follow:

```py
class ApplicantListView(ListView):

    model = Applicant
    paginate_by = 100 
    template_name = 'applicant_list.html'
```

and the model

```py
    class Work(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        body = models.TextField()
        published = models.BooleanField(False)
        date = models.DateTimeField()
                
        def __str__ (self):
            return self.title
        
    
    class Applicant(models.Model):
        name= models.CharField(max_length=200)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
        country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
        work= models.ForeignKey(Work, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        upload = models.FileField(upload_to='up/')
        
        def __str__ (self):
            return self.name
```

so what I would like to achieve is to show only the applicants for the work ID used in the URL path. At the moment it shows all the records disregarding the pk used in the path.

Answer (score 2):

You can customise the queryset;

```py
class ApplicantListView(ListView):

    model = Applicant
    paginate_by = 100 
    template_name = 'applicant_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(work_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

Then your `Applicant` list will be filtered by those objects where the `work_id` matches the ID in the URL.

Comment: thanks a lot for your prompt reply. How is this diferent vs. def get_queryset(self):
  return Applicant.objects.filter(work_id=self.request.resolver_match.kwargs['pk'])

Comment: I'd recommend letting django handle the queryset in the super, then filtering it. In terms of accessing the param, you've put the kwarg in the path so you might as well access it from there because when the class is setup the kwargs are attached to `self`.